# Compute Gradient and Hessian of following function

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, normed-spaces

can anyone help me and give me directions to compute the gradient and the hessian matrix of this function : $$f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^+}$$
$$f(x)=\|Ax-(x^TAx)x\|.$$
Thank you

Comment: You can start by $n=1$, then the general function will be not very much different.